# New user in redshift can't run \dt

Tags: amazon-redshift

I've created a new redshift user like such:

```
CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER GROUP group ADD USER user;
grant usage on schema test;
```

however after connecting to the database i can't run basic commands.

```
dev=> \dt
ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_class
```

What step am I missing? Thanks.